# Executing HTTPS from SQL Server procedure

Tags: sql-server, https, http-proxy

I am trying to do HTTPS GET in a SQL Server 2008 stored procedure. I am able to connect to local system but when I try to connect to production server which is internet facing, I am getting `status <> 0`.

I am trying to connect from behind a corporate proxy.

Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

I am trying to use this procedure from triggers.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[HTTP_Request]
AS
    Declare @url varchar(2000)
    Declare @res varchar(2000)
    Declare @err varchar(2000)

    Declare @obj int, @hr int, @status int, @msg varchar(255)

    Declare @response varchar(2000)
    Declare @error varchar(2000)

    set @url = 'https://<url>'
    /*exec HTTP_POST @url, @res, @err 
    select @res
    Select @err*/
    set @sUrl= 'https://<url>'

    exec @hr = sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHttp', @obj OUT
    -- exec @hr = sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHttp', @obj OUT

    if @hr <> 0
    begin 
        Raiserror('sp_OACreate MSXML2.ServerXMLHttp.3.0 failed', 16, 1) 
        return 
    end

    exec @hr = sp_OAMethod @obj, 'open', NULL, 'GET', @sUrl, true

    if @hr <> 0 
    begin 
        set @msg = 'sp_OAMethod Open failed' 
        goto eh  
    end

    exec @hr = sp_OAMethod @obj, 'setRequestHeader', NULL, 'Content-Type', 'application/json'

    if @hr <> 0 
    begin 
        set @msg = 'sp_OAMethod setRequestHeader failed' 
        goto eh 
    end

    -- Setting Authorization --
    exec @hr = sp_OAMethod @obj, 'setRequestHeader', NULL, 'Authorization', 'Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4='

    if @hr <> 0  
    begin 
        set @msg = 'sp_OAMethod setRequestHeader failed' 
        goto eh 
    end


exec @hr = sp_OAMethod @obj, send, NULL, ''
if @hr <>0 begin set @msg = 'sp_OAMethod Send failed' goto eh end


exec @hr = sp_OAGetProperty @obj, 'status', @status OUT
if @hr <>0 begin set @msg = 'sp_OAMethod read status failed' goto
eh
end


if @status <> 200 begin set @msg = 'sp_OAMethod http status ' +
str(@status) goto eh end



exec @hr = sp_OAGetProperty @obj, 'responseText', @response OUT
if @hr <>0 begin set @msg = 'sp_OAMethod read response failed' goto
eh end

select @status


exec @hr = sp_OADestroy @obj
return
eh:
exec @hr = sp_OADestroy @obj
set @error = @msg

select @status
select @msg
select @error

GO
```

Comment: SQL Server just isn't designed and intended to call out to external web services - and you should **most definitely** not do this inside a trigger! A trigger **must be** very fast, nimble, short lived - since it executes in the scope of the transcation that caused it to fire. **DO NOT** put heavy lifting, large calculations, or external calls into a trigger! This will **kill** your system performance! Rethink your design and avoid external calls from within triggers at all cost

Comment: I get what you are saying. But I am tightly bound by the requirement. I have to call external system when an insert happens. I've designed web service such that it returns in milliseconds and is not doing any heavy-lifting (Only n/w latency may cause issue, but I am fine with this).

Comment: I need to bypass PROXY